# How to specify "EntityContainer" metadata output when using EdmBuilder.GetEdm<DbContext>()?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata, breeze, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am working with OData, Breeze, and Code First Entity Framework. I recently switched from ODataConventionModelBuilder to EdmBuilder and running into some issues.

I have two classes "Soldier" and "Dependent" that inherit from an abstract class "Person". These entities show up fine as **EntityTypes** in the schema but only the abstract class "Person" appears in the **EntityContainer**. Is there a way to configure the EDM to **ignore the abstract class** and instead give **access to the inherited classes**? Or at a minimum just give me access to all three?

In my DBContext I have:

```
    ...
    public virtual DbSet<Soldier> Soldiers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Dependent> Dependents { get; set; }
    ...
```

each have their own "EntityTypeConfiguration":

```
public class SoldierConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Soldier>
    {
        public SoldierConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("Soldiers");

            ...
        }
    }
```

Resulting metadata (just container, the whole thing is too large):

```
<EntityContainer xmlns:p5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2013/11/edm/customannotation" Name="ApplicationDBContext" p5:UseClrTypes="true">
...
<EntitySet Name="People" EntityType="Site.Models.Person"/>
...
</EntityContainer>
```

You can see that only people shows up even though I want to query against Soldiers.

Comment: We're facing a [somewhat similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32250002/issue-with-inheritance-with-webapi-odata-v3-and-breezejs). Were you able to find a solution or workaround?